# Using ng-show to expand nested list on click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

[My code - Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2qvLlr2fwwyCQCi64iTs?p=preview)

I used `ng-repeat` to render my nested `list`.
the `list` built in a way of a `folder` which is always displayed 
and `files` which are displayed when parent `folder` is clicked.

The problem is when I use `ng-show` to display `files` all my `folders` are open
and not the clicked one only.

e.g

[image: E.g]

I want only the clicked record in the list to be expanded and not all records.
I understand why it happens and I'm looking for a way in `Angular` to solve this issue.
How can I achieve that?

**My code**

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', []);

//controllers
webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope, Votes) {
    $scope.votes  = Votes;

    $scope.show = false;

    $scope.expand = function() {
       console.log("show")
       $scope.show = true;
    }
});


//services


webApp.factory('Votes', [function() {

    //temporary repository till integration with DB this will be translated into restful get query
    var votes = [
        {
            id: '1',
            created: 1381583344653,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '4',
            rate: 5,
            ip: '198.168.0.0',
            status: 'Approved',
            folder:[
                {
                    id: '1',
                    created: 1381583344653,
                    updated: '222212',
                    ratingID: '4',
                    rate: 5,
                    ip: '198.168.0.0',
                    status: 'Approved',
                },
                {
                    id: '111',
                    created: 1381583344653,
                    updated: '222212',
                    ratingID: '4',
                    rate: 5,
                    ip: '198.168.0.0',
                    status: 'Approved'
                }
              ]
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            created: 1382387322693,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 1,
            ip: '198.168.0.1',
            status: 'Approved',
            folder:[
                {
                    id: '2',
                    created: 1382387322693,
                    updated: '222212',
                    ratingID: '3',
                    rate: 1,
                    ip: '198.168.0.1',
                    status: 'Approved',
                },
                {
                    id: '22',
                    created: 1382387322693,
                    updated: '222212',
                    ratingID: '3',
                    rate: 1,
                    ip: '198.168.0.1',
                    status: 'Approved'
                },
                {
                    id: '222',
                    created: 1382387327693,
                    updated: '222212',
                    ratingID: '3',
                    rate: 1,
                    ip: '198.168.0.1',
                    status: 'Approved'
                },
              ]
        },
        {
          file:[
              {
                id: '231',
                created: 1392387327693,
                updated: '222212',
                ratingID: '1',
                rate: 1,
                ip: '198.168.2.1',
                status: 'Approved'
              }
            ]
        }
    ];

    return votes;
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li class="created">
            <b>CREATED</b>
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            <b>IP ADDRESS</b>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="expand()">

        <li class="created">
            {{vote.created|date}}
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            {{vote.ip}}
        </li>


        <ul ng-show="show" ng-repeat="file in vote.folder">
          <li class="created">
              {{file.created|date}}
          </li>
          <li class="ip">
              {{file.ip}}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="file" ng-repeat="file in vote.file">
            <li class="created">
                {{file.created|date}}
            </li>
            <li class="ip">
               {{file.ip}}
            </li>
        </ul>

    </ul>

   </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you need more granularity for your `show`.  maybe a `show` for every folder?

Comment: Well I cannot tell how many folders there are and I'm using `ng-repeat` so it is quite impossible

Comment: not impossible, javascript is dynamic so you can add a property to each the things you are repeating.  Or, create something other data structure that you are repeating that includes a show.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing is normal. In the current state of your code there is only one show attribute and all your blocks are bound to this attribute. Modifying the value from false to true will result in refreshing all your blocks. Show attribute being set to true everything will be expanded.

What you need to do is for every votes add an attributes show and bound the show/hide state to this attribute. Something like :

```
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="expand(vote)">
  <li class="created">{{vote.created|date}}</li>
  <li class="ip">{{vote.ip}}</li>
  <li ng-show="vote.show">
    <ul>
      <li  ng-repeat="file in vote.folder">
```

And your expand function will look like :

```
$scope.expand = function(vote) {
   vote.show = true;
}
```

See the modified Plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/gRtg4157Z3kDbNpejvFW?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, does this is the correct way to create expandable `lists` with `ng-show`? Aren't there any other `css/html` solutions?

Comment: it s one of the ways to do it. You can also use ng-if instead of ng-show. With ng-show the html markup will be created and only a display:none/block will be applied. With ng-if no markup will be added until the expression is evaluated to true. Be careful if you have a lot of nested folders/files you may consider doing some recursivity. See the answer of this question http://bit.ly/13Q28gI . Finally if you want this piece of code to appear all accros your web app you can create a directive http://bit.ly/IKvJLC

Comment: Is it possible to give an example to this with ng-if?

Comment: See this new Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/GsYGHNFdKNpqr5rVW6NR?p=preview BTW to use ng-if your angular version needs to be 1.1.5 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of Nics answer, this is slightly more simple:

```
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="expand = !expand">
  <li class="created">{{vote.created|date}}</li>
  <li class="ip">{{vote.ip}}</li>
  <li ng-show="expand>
    <ul>
      <li  ng-repeat="file in vote.folder">
```